# STL sort question

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I have vector of structures:

```
vector<Custom> myvec;
```

Custom is a structure:

```
struct Custom
{
   double key[3];
};
```

How to sort *myvec* by *key[0]. key[1]* or *key[2]* using STL sort algorithm?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write a custom comparator:

```
template <int i> struct CustomComp
{
  bool operator()( const Custom& lhs, const Custom& rhs) const
  {
    return lhs.key[i]<rhs.key[i];
  }
};
```

and then sort e.g. by using `std::sort(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(),CustomComp<0>());` (this sorts by the first key entry)

Or with a more recent compiler (with c++0x lambda support):

```
std::sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(),
  []( const Custom& lhs, const Custom& rhs) {return lhs.key[0] < rhs.key[0];}
);
```

Comment: "Make it work, profile, make it fast" - no reason to optimize when it isn't neccessary. Using a template prevents you from selecting an index at runtime, that's why I didn't do it.

Comment: I didn't pick the template version over the non-template version just for optimization or speed reasons. I also find it cleaner since you don't need to define member variables and a constructor. Not saying that the argument to use a member variable is void, but it can be used against the very decision too: why over-engineer and implement some feature that you do not need?

Comment: Because the feature doesn't hurt you - it doesn't make the interface more complex, it doesn't make the class more likely to break, it doesn't require additional typing when using it (even less) ...

Comment: @itjax: What if I want to use STL sort inside loop with variable instead of <0>?

Comment: If you really want to use a loop, it is probably better to use etarion's variant. Using mine, you can use a switch statement to switch between different template variants, but that's usually not what I'd recommend.

Answer (score 10):

By using a a custom comparator.

```
struct CustomLess {
    size_t idx;
    CustomLess(size_t i) : idx(i) {}
    bool operator()(Custom const& a, Custom const& b) const {
        return a.key[idx] < b.key[idx];
    }
};
```

then

```
std::sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), CustomLess(1)); // for 1
```

Note: I did not use a template because, while using a template enables the compiler to optimize for that specific index, it prevents you from selecting the index at runtime, e.g. based on userinput, so it's less flexible/can't do as much as the nontemplated version. And as we all know, premature optimization is evil :)

Comment: +1, the simplest way to do so. `template <size_t idx> struct CustomLess` trades flexibility for efficiency. But you'd only choose it after profiling

Comment: You are missing a `()` for the `operator`

Comment: It is missing a `const` too :)

Comment: Diego, that's what he meant with "efficiency". The non-templated version can be used to select indexes at runtime, the templated one can be optimized better. Thanks for pointing out the errors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why so many of the answers posted are focusing on functors.  There is no need for a functor with the OP's stated requirement.  Here are 2 non-functor solutions:

1:  Overload operator< in the Custom class

```
bool Custom::operator< (const Custom& rhs)
{
    return key[0] < rhs.key[0];
}

// can call sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end());
```

2:  Create a custom comparison function

```
template<int i> bool CustomLess(const Custom& lhs, const Custom& rhs)
{
    return lhs.key[i] < rhs.key[i];
}

// can call sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), CustomLess<0>);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool CompareCustoms(const Custom& lhs, const Custom& rhs)
{
    // Compare criteria here
    return (lhs.key[0] < rhs.key[0]);
}
sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), CompareCustoms);
```

Comment: Whoops, I see the much cleaner answers above here. I've learnt something too :).

Comment: @hillel: In general, function objects are better for this than functions. They inline better than functions called by address and they allow to carry state with the function (instead of having to store it globally).

Comment: @sbi: I'm often lazy with creating proper functors and I never took inlining into account. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @sbi:  They are only better if the need requires them to be.  For a simple Less operation, there is no need for a functor; a template version of hillel's function would meet the need of the OP and be easier to read and maintain than a functor.  The OP could have eliminated the need for either by simply overloading the < operator.

Comment: @Zac: When would you _not_ prefer comparison to be inlined? That's when a function might be as good as a function object.

Comment: @sbi:  From a maintenance point of view, having thousands of custom 1-off functors is a pain.  It is MUCH easier to maintain a few comparison functions written to be shared among various types of objects.  In my experience, functors are most useful when the state of the functor needs to be passed along with it.  As I said, for a simple less operation, simply overloading the `operator<` is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @Zac: I might be dense, but I don't get why you think you can re-use "a few comparison functions", but not functors. Where's the difference?

Comment: @sbi:  You can, if you create them generically (e.g. the `less<T>` functor in STL).  But in practice, if you are creating something as simple as this, you tend to be re-creating the wheel.  Overloading `operator<` will use a standard, well-tested, functor while making your code easier to maintain.  If your comparison doesn't need to maintain state, the inline benefit you get is the same as writing a simple function (since dereferencing a function pointer is comparable to passing an object with no data by value), so why muddle your object hierarchy with objects that really should be functions?

Comment: @Zac: "...in practice, if you are creating a simple like this, you tend to be re-creating the wheel" No, I don't. If I can make _functions_ that can be re-used, I can certainly make _functors_ that can be re-used. I don't see why I wouldn't, and what you write sounds awfully like "I prefer a bike over a trike, because a bike can have round wheels".

Comment: @sbi:  You misunderstand that part of my point.  STL already has several functors (less, greater, greater_equal, etc).  If you are doing something simple like these functors already do, writing your own to do the same thing is duplicating code (wasteful).

Comment: @Zac: You seem to have lost track of what is discussed here. We were talking whether a custom functor would be better than hillel's custom function (as I said) or whether "they are only better if the need requires them to be" (as you said). I maintained that functors are commonly inlined, while functions called through pointers are not, which is why I believe functors always have at least this one advantage over functions, all semantical matters (state) left aside. You seem to want to counter that argument, only I don't understand what you are countering it with.

Comment: @sbi:  I'll try to narrow it to that single point of discussion:  Functors are inlined, but are passed by value.  Thus, if a functor has no state, the default copy-constructor is called for every comparison.  This expense is comparable to dereferencing a function pointer, which negates the advantage of using functors in that situation.  All you end up doing in that case is hiding the purpose of the code (a comparison is a function - you are hiding it in an object when there is no reason to do so).  Additionally, most of the non-state functors you would need are already implemented in STL.

Comment: @Zac: Function pointers need to be copied, too. And if a functor has no state (no data members), then copying might well be fully optimized away (just as copying a function pointer). But even if we consider stateful functors, _copying_ would only be relevant for _recursive_ algorithms, while _calling_ is relevant for _iterative_ algorithms as well. I'm not sure there actually are any recursive algorithms in the STL, but there's a hell of a lot of iterative ones. Also, a functor "hides" its purpose only to those uninitiated to basic C++. And we're talking _custom_ operations, not off-the-shelf.

Comment: @sbi:  Which is exactly my point:  There is no performance gain by using a functor over a function if there is no state to be used.  In fact, functions can actually perform better than functors in those cases.  A void pointer only hides its purpose to the uninitiated as well, but you wouldn't use those either.  Use the syntax that suits the purpose.  Comparisons with no state are functional, so use functions.

Comment: @Zac: How in the world can you draw from my comment the conclusion that functions are faster than functors when I argued the other way around?? And again without any counter arguments from your side! I herewith officially give up. This discussion style is too enraging and you're not to be persuaded by reasoning. I value my time and sanity.

Comment: @sbi:  "Function pointers need to be copied, too. And if a functor has no state (no data members), then copying might well be fully optimized away (just as copying a function pointer)."  In other words, there is no difference.  In fact, writing a simple test program to sort the exact same list of an N sized vector of randomly generated numbers (stored in a simple class), a custom function performed better than a custom functor, which performed only slightly better than just using `less<T>`.  The problem with using comments to discuss this is the character limit.

Comment: @sbi:  History has shown that it is nearly impossible to reason with a zealot that is convinced, through years of repetition, that they are right.